# Hardlink or Symlink a portable HDD as Webroot?

Tags: nautilus, fstab, symbolic-link

I'm setting up a local development environment for our server, and (due to capacity limitations on my SSD) I need to use an external drive as my Webroot (/var/www in my case).

The real question is, should I hardlink this directory or symlink?

If I symlink OR hardlink, will my computer remember the drive (regardless of USB) next time it is plugged in, or will I have to renew my link?

Is there a best practices method for using longterm external storage as an internal resource?

Lastly, how would I link this up under my Nautilus Desktop launcher? (nautilus-home.desktop)  -- would I have to link a link in `/` ?

Not sure if this is the right road to pursue, but I added

```
# portable on /dev/sdc1
UUID=a8ff783b-017e-462c-b995-708f8823bdc3 none            ext4    defaults        0       0
```

to `/etc/fstab` where UUID is the UUID of my external.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might be better off adding a line for it in the fstab and mounting it in the place you want it. You can read more about how to do this here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: Will fstab'ing it change as I move it around my USB ports though?